# tcl var substitution in sqlite3 eval

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I have a file filled with sqlite statements I'd like to parse. I've done so previously using the C-interface but now I have trouble with the Tcl interface.

```
sqlite3 cspdb ":memory:"
set s [read [set f [open csp_sql.txt]]]
set ms [string map {"\n" "\0"} $s]
puts $ms
cspdb eval {$ms}
```

The error I get is:

> "near "$ms": syntax error while executing cspdb eval {$ms}"

It works fine when I paste the output from puts $ms directly into the eval brackets. I also tried "{$ms}" and just plain $ms but the result is the same; syntax error.

I might chose another solution for the problem all together but it really bugs my why it does not work...

---

Here is what the file looks like:

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    CREATE TABLE Symbol (
      Label TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
      Type TEXT DEFAULT('no_type')
    );

    CREATE TABLE Process (
      Name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      Type TEXT DEFAULT('no_type')
    );

    CREATE TABLE Named_Process (
      Label TEXT UNIQUE,
      Definition INTEGER UNIQUE,
      FOREIGN KEY(Label) REFERENCES Symbol (Label),
      FOREIGN KEY(Definition) REFERENCES Definition(Name)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Definition (
      Name INTEGER UNIQUE,
      Definition INTEGER,
      FOREIGN KEY(Name) REFERENCES Process(Name),
      FOREIGN KEY(Definition) REFERENCES Process(Name)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Reference (
      Name INTEGER UNIQUE,
      Reference TEXT,
      FOREIGN KEY(Name) REFERENCES Process(Name),
      FOREIGN KEY(Reference) REFERENCES Definition(Name)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Event (
      Label TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
      Type TEXT DEFAULT('no_type')
    );

    CREATE TABLE Environment (
      Label TEXT UNIQUE,
      FOREIGN KEY (Label) REFERENCES Event (Label)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Prefix (
      Name INTEGER UNIQUE,
      P INTEGER,
      Event TEXT,
      FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES Process (Name),
      FOREIGN KEY (P) REFERENCES Process (Name),
      FOREIGN KEY (Event) REFERENCES Event (Label)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Choice (
      Name INTEGER UNIQUE,
      P INTEGER,
      Q INTEGER,
      FOREIGN KEY(Name) REFERENCES Process(Name),
      FOREIGN KEY(P) REFERENCES Process(Name),
      FOREIGN KEY(Q) REFERENCES Process(Name)
    );

    /* Language defined processes */
    /* SKIP */
    INSERT INTO Symbol(Label,Type) VALUES('SKIP','named_process');
    INSERT INTO Named_Process(Label) VALUES('SKIP');
    INSERT INTO Process(type) VALUES('definition');
    UPDATE Named_Process SET Definition=last_insert_rowid() WHERE Label='SKIP';
    INSERT INTO Definition(Name,Definition) VALUES(last_insert_rowid(),last_insert_rowid());

  END TRANSACTION;
```

(Not so sure removing newlines is necessary...)

Answer (score 4):

If the string that you've read from the file is SQL, you should be able to do this:

```
sqlite3 cspdb ":memory:"

set f [open "csp_sql.txt"]
set sql [read $f]
close $f

cspdb eval $sql
```

By comparison, the literal string `$ms` is not a valid SQL statement or query, nor is it syntactically legal to surround a SQL statement with braces (which is what `"{$ms}"` ended up doing; the outer `"`…`"` makes the inside just a bunch of characters).

I don't know why you are translating newlines into NULs, but that's *really* unlikely to be a good idea. Bulk import of data (possibly with NULs in it) should be done in a different way.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's best to keep the number of actual substitutions in SQL code really small as it is hard to get them right. Bound parameters are far more reliable and much easier to use in practice; the Tcl interface to SQLite strongly prefers _named_ bound parameters, coupling them to Tcl variables by default.

Comment: turns out the newline-to-null was the issue

Answer (score 1):

The `eval` subcommand created by Sqlite does limited variable substitution, but only in places where a string value is expected.

Try

```
cspdb eval $ms
```

to let the Tcl interpreter substitute the SQL statements before sending them to `eval`.

Comment: suggestion yields "near " ": syntax error while executing
"cspdb eval $ms""

Comment: you were right, the line works if the value of $ms is legit. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

turns out the newline-to-null was the culprit making substitution fail. final working code:

```
sqlite3 cspdb ":memory:"
cspdb eval [read [set f [open csp_sql.txt]]]
```

the reason newline-to-null turned up at all was when trying to debug making the string match my original working C-code which used multiline string literals in which newlines diappeared. Except, "\0" is not a "disappearing" character...